# create relationship between posts from one category and posts from another category

Tags: categories, metabox

What I'm trying to do is adding in a post admin page a meta box, dynamically listing all posts from another category in the for of a check box list.

This way I can create relations between a post and other posts belonging to a different category.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the Question/Task?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you're asking, but maybe Scribu's [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin will help you.